# Text within two strings into separate new files named based on the found text

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a file which has lot of text following a pattern as

```
SOME STRING1 some text in the same line SOME STRING2  
lot of text in multiple lines~
```

What I want to achieve?

1. I need to extract each text block between `SOME STRING1` and the symbol `~`
2. The filenames should be the text which is within `STRING1` and `STRING2`.

I was able to extract the text blocks but I could not figure out how to write these into separate files based on the next pattern.

```
$txtfile = gc -Raw '.\mytxt.txt'
$output = $txtfile | select-string -AllMatches '(?i)some\s+string1(.|\n)*?~'
$output.Matches
```

A for each loop on the Matches to look for Value gives the matched pattern. But I could not figure out how to write each matched pattern to a separate file by looking into the matched pattern again to find the text with SOME STRING 1 and SOME STRING 2.

Here is a sample text:

```
SOME STRING1 bqo_cha.paliuni_cdr SOME STRING2
 paliunipaliuni_cdr.bgr, paliuni_cdr.vdr
   KEY jaja.paliuni_cdr~

SOME STRING1 bqo_cha.ytr SOME STRING2
SOME STRING1 bqo_cha.ytr SOME STRING2 paliuni KEY jaja.ytr ~

SOME STRING1 bqo_cha.unipali_bfrentmng SOME STRING2
 paliuniunipali_bfrentmng.ngt
   KEY jaja.unipali_bfrentmng~

SOME STRING1 bqo_cha.unipali_iliwi SOME STRING2
 paliuniunipali_iliwi.iliwi_jhwity
  KEY jaja.unipali_iliwi~
```

Comment: FYI: Do not use `(.|\n)*?`, use `.*?` with the `s` inline modifier. In your case, `'(?si)some\s+string1.*?~'`. Or you may just use ``'(?i)some\s+string1[^~]*~'``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of matching on `(.|\n)`, use a negated character set like `[^~]` - and then explicitly grab the first part (the file name) in a capture group:

```
$output = $txtfile|Select-String -AllMatches '(?i)some\s+string1\s*(?<value>(?<filename>.*)\s*some\s+string2[^~]*)~'
foreach($match in $output.Matches){
  $Filename = $match.Groups['filename'].Value.Trim()
  $Value = $match.Groups['value'].Value
  Set-Content -Path $Filename -Value $Value
}
```

Comment: Thank you! How to make the matching string part of the matched group?